# configure restful routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a restful web service in a rails application. I need to configure a restful routes as below.

```
localhost:3000/books/<book_name>/new/<parameters to create Book Item>

    Eg:  http://localhost:3000/books/sherlock/new/id/123/business/<BU>/.../{other parameters}
```

How do I configure it in the routes and access the params in controller. Please help.

Comment: check out michael heartls rail book, it's free online. it teaches you all about this stuff! the whoel thing is basically an incredibly well written and executed tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called "route globbing". 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

However, if I were you - I'd used "default" query params. For many reasons.